Find a Galois Extension $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a Galois group of order $64$
I am given the hint to use cyclotomic extensions and Sylow's theorems. Here is my development so far:
Note that the extension $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{193}) $ over $\mathbb{Q} $ is Galois, and since $ 193 $ is prime, $ |\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})| = \varphi(193) = 192 = 2^6 \cdot 3 $. By Sylow's first theorem, there exists a subgroup of $ \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) $ of order $ 64 $.
From here, I am unsure how to proceed, as I am not certain that this subgroup of order $ 64 $ is precisely the Galois group of some extension. Any help would be appreciated.

The group ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ is cyclic since $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ is cyclic when $p$ is prime.
In an abelian Galois extension $E/F$, each subgroup $H$ of $G := {\rm Gal}(E/F)$ is normal and that implies its fixed field $L$ is Galois over $F$ with ${\rm Gal}(L/F) \cong G/H$.  Show the example ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)$ that you are looking at has a quotient group of order $64$.

By Sylow's theorems, there exists a subgroup of $G = \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ of order 3. Let $H$ be that subgroup of order 3. Since $G$ is cyclic, it is abelian, and thus every subgroup is normal. In particular, $H$ is normal, so if $L$ is the fixed field of $H$, then $L$ is a Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ and furthermore
$$\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G/H$$
where, by Lagrange's theorem, we get that $|\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})| = |G|/|H| = 64$.
Is that all?

@JadMON2k1 That's perfect :)

@Don Thanks, but... Is there no way to explicitly find $L$? Or is that description of $L$ sufficient?

@JadMON2k1 For your problem this definitely suffices. If still you want to write the field $L$ explicitly, you should first find a generator, say $g$, of $(\mathbb{Z}/193)^\times$. Then the subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order 3 is cyclic generated by $\sigma: \zeta \mapsto \zeta^{g^{64}}$. Now $L$ is the set of elements of $K$ fixed by $\sigma$.
